# Removing Tags on product reviews by XML

Tags: magento-1.9

I have set the products tags off in the Admin but they are still shown in the product reviews.

I have try to add to local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
<reference name="product.info.additional">
    <action method="unsetChild"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
</reference>
```

But i still have the tabs in the product reviews.
should i call something else rahter

```
<catalog_product_view>
```

Comment: <catalog_product_view><remove name="product_tag_list"/></catalog_product_view> use this

Comment: Thanks amit , but i have only add in the local the code :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using a local.xml then just use this code:

```
<remove name="product_tag_list" />
```

Using local.xml is the best way to modify your page. Also the easy way btw. Better then just disabling it via backend. for it would be better for your store performance.

OR if you are using your custom theme this [link](http://www.w3bdeveloper.com/how-to/how-to-remove-the-tags-block-from-product-page/) will be helpful to you

*i am not associated with above link any how. this is just for your knowledge*

hope this will be help you.